# I am having an error with callback function

Tags: node.js, express

I just started developing with express and I am creating a category route, in order to create a new category for my ecommerce site. I am having this error "Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]". I really do not understand what the issue is... I have tried by reading a bunch or articles/documentation. Any idea what the issue is ?

here is my server.js

```
const express=require('express');
const app= express();
const cors=require('cors');
const connectDB= require('./database/db');
const morgan= require('morgan');
const authRoutes= require ('./routes/auth')
const categoryRoutes = require ('./routes/category');

//middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('/api/category', categoryRoutes);

connectDB();

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));

app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
 res.send(' hello server')
})
```

here is my controller:

```
exports.categoryController = (req, res)=>{
console.log('Inside category Controller')
}
```

here is my route:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const categoryController = require('../routes/controllers/category');

router.post('/', categoryController);

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller file actually exports an object exposing your controller function as a `categoryController` property.

Either import it as:

```
const { categoryController } = require('../routes/controllers/category');
```

Or change your controller to directly export the controller function:

```
module.exports = (req, res)=>{
  console.log('Inside category Controller')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the misunderstanding of export in ES6. For easy understanding: exports is a object than can containt your methods that you are expected to use them in another file. So basically, when using that exports object in another file, there will be 2 options:

1 - Using destructuring variable `const {method} = require(...)`

2 - Assign one object to that exports object `const objectA = require(...)`

For option 1, you can use it directly just like the methods in same file

For option 2, you can use it through assigned object, such as: `objectA.method`